# Best GIS database for Brazil geological data

Tags: data-request, database, brazil

I'm looking for a database for the underground resources of Brazil, especially for the state of Minas Gerais. Do you have any to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Which resources? Timber is everywhere. Farmland is not tracked. Oil and iron will be in a few areas. Just look at some resource maps and manually  enter. Most resources are associated ores and will not be specifically mined for.

Comment: timber and farmland are not underground. can you give more details and/or be more specific?

Comment: That's all there is

Comment: You'll only find a few dozen deposits and some will be huge and vaguely  defined.

Comment: Have you look into Brazil 's Geology departments there ? They maybe help you out on that